# Running WMI query on Win32_ScheduledJob returns no results

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to query a remote computer using WMI to get its scheduled tasks (two specifically) but the query returns nothing. I've tried running it against my local machine and it still returns no results. But if i query Win32_LogicalDisk it returns 3 results. To me that says WMI is working locally it just returns nothing for Scheduled jobs. I find that odd because when I run `schtasks` from a command prompt I get back about 25 tasks (maybe more) The following code is nothing fancy. I've commented out things I've tried, right now it is set to run against my machine locally.

```
public Win32_ScheduledJob QueryTask(string systemName, string p2)
{
    var job = new Win32_ScheduledJob();
    var connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions()
    {
        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    };
    var computer = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\CIMV2", systemName);
    //var scope = new ManagementScope(computer);
    //scope.Connect();
    //var str = "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk";
    var str = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ScheduledJob";
    var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(str);
    var tasks = query.Get();
    //TODO search for Name==p2 and set its elements to job
    var count = tasks.Count;
    tasks.Dispose();
    return job;
}
```

any idea why I am getting no results? Oh i forgot to mention that I once used query.Get(???ManagementOO???) and subscribed to the 4 events and it calls completed with status of NoError but never calls Progress, ObjectReady, or ObjectPut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Win32_ScheduledJob` class is internally using the `AT` protocol, which is **bound to deprecation** starting with *Windows 8* and *Windows Server 2012*. As a first step the `AT` protocol is disabled by default. If the protocol is disabled, for example calling the `Create` method on a `Win32_ScheduledJob` object will fail with error `0x8`. You can turn the `AT` protocol back on by adding the following registry entry:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Configuration 
Name: EnableAt 
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1
```

You may need to restart the machine to make the setting effective.

[Resource: `Win32_ScheduledJob` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394399(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Tried it with no success... Even after restart...

FYI:

```
==>schtasks|find /C "TaskName"
59
```

Comment: Thank you. I suppose had I read all of the class I would have seen what you put here. Looks like the safest route is to use the Task Scheduler API which was hinted at right after

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/root/cimv2` change the namespace to `/Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler` and instead of `SELECT * FROM Win32_ScheduledJob` change it to `SELECT * FROM MSFT_ScheduledTask`.
Within the object/class `MSFT_ScheduledTask` pick your items like `TaskName`

One Example in vba/vbs:

```vbs
Dim objItems As Object
Dim objItem As Object

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &H10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &H20

Set objItems = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\Root\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler").ExecQuery("" & _
"SELECT * FROM MSFT_ScheduledTask", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In objItems
    Debug.Print objItem.TaskName
Next
```

Hint:
If you execute `Get-ScheduledTasks` in Powershell you see the CimClass which I have used above. You can transfer this knowledge to other cases where you know the CimClass and the object.

Comment: lol. this was 7 years ago. I have no idea where that code is now :D Why the changes though? What's different between what I have and what you suggest?

Comment: Had the same problem within vba and got the solution. Win32_ScheduledJob was deprecated and does not give results back. Using the object from an other namespace which powershell is actually also using solves the problem. Nevertheless... 7 years are a long time ;)

Comment: For powershell, looks like it's Get-scheduledtask, not tasks. And you can use CImSession to remote it. Alternatively, using the namespace and name provided above, this works (thanks!!): `gwmi -namespace Root\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler -class msft_scheduledtask -computername myserver`